# Read Multiple Modbus devices

Tags: datagridview, timer, modbus, response-time

I am working on a project based on the [Shortbus dll RTU](https://sites.google.com/site/shortbusdll) . I have managed to read the devices, but as the number of devices increases, the delay for each read goes up too much.

I am using a separate timer for each device but I am not getting anywhere since I have to write the value to the database and compare old and new value to display a "working" and "not working" status.

I want 227 devices scanned but I'm not achieving the response I need with only 32 devices.

I am using a datagridview to store the port and the Modbus ID

http://postimage.org/' target='_blank'>http://s2.postimg.org/x1gdrkug9/modbus.gif' border='0' alt="modbus" />
http://postimage.org/index.php?lang=spanish'>share image

Code for Reading each row

```
private void lectura(int numerofila)
    {
        try
        {
            Variables.fila_actual = numerofila + 1;
             ushort err;
            Variables.sb1.SetCOMPort(Convert.ToUInt16(gridConf.Rows[con].Cells[4].Value), 9600, 8, 'N', 2);
            Variables.sb1.SetCOMPort(Convert.ToUInt16(gridConf.Rows[numerofila].Cells[4].Value), 9600, 8, 'N', 2);
            err = Variables.sb1.ReadWords(Convert.ToUInt16(gridConf.Rows[numerofila].Cells[3].Value), 1004, 1, out Variables.read,  type3x: true);          
            gridConf.Rows[numerofila].Cells[7].Value = Variables.read[0];
   }
        catch
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Error in row " + Variables.numero_filas);
        }

    }
```

Grid View of Scanned Values

http://postimage.org/' target='_blank'>http://s11.postimg.org/7544cqyoj/modbus2.gif' border='0' alt="modbus2" />
http://postimage.org/index.php?lang=spanish'>subir foto

And at each tick of 2 seconds I perform the readings based on the number of row

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lectura(0);

    }
```

I tried threads but they clogged the app. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the Visual Studio Profiling tools to identify the bottlenecks? I think it would be helpful to know where the time is spent and whether or not you can take any action.

Comment: "[...] but as the number of devices increases, the delay for each read goes up too much"... Do you mean that a single read takes more time or that the time between two subsequent reads of the same device gets longer? Note that the latter would be more than normal in multi-drop half-duplex serial communication (I suppose that's your case). In other words, polling time increases, but a single read (request-response) should always take almost the same amount of time.

Comment: the problem comes with the function 'err = Variables.sb1.ReadWords(1, 1004, 1, out Variables.read, delay: 100, type3x: true'. Too much time is spent reading each value in a linear way because when I read them with parallel for or for each values become 0. I will look after the profiling tools to identify the time consuming statements.